# Piwigo "Abort pclzip.lib.php : Missing zlib extensions" error

Tags: php, zlib

I'm trying to install the Community Plugin for Piwigo and am getting the following error:

`Abort pclzip.lib.php : Missing zlib extensions`

I've been searching and trying as much as I can and still am not able to solve this issue. It looks to be something about `gzopen` really now being `gzopen64`.

I have verified I have zlib installed. I have the latest and greatest Piwigo 2.8.0.

I've found these and tried them - sadly it hasn't helped:

http://www.thomasmonaco.com/pclzip-lib-php-missing-zlib-extensions/
https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=33684

This issue was supposed to be fixed in 2.7.2 per the following link:
http://piwigo.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=23759

However I don't know HOW to implement this fix.

Any help is extremely appreciated.

```
Piwigo version: 2.8.0
PHP version: 5.6.19
MySQL version: 5.6.27
Piwigo URL: http://{localserver}/piwigo
```

Comment: The issue is that PHP wasn't compiled `--with-zlib`. Can you recompile your PHP stack?

Comment: Any good tutorials on how to do that?

Comment: I've been trying to find any sort of tutorial on how to recompile Php with zlib on Freenas/linux and I'm not able to find anything. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Freenas. But you also mention Linux?

Comment: Freenas is similar to Linux with similar commands it seems. Do you know how to recompile php with zlib in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out solution.

the PHP wasn't compiled with zlib that @OhgodWhy pointed out.

I went to /usr/ports/lang/php56 and did `make deinstall clean`

then reinstalled `php56` with the `php56-zlib` module.

And everything works!